# Ubuntu 13.04 does not recognize wireless adapter (14e4:4365)

Tags: wireless, broadcom, adapter

I replaced Windows 8 on my laptop with Ubuntu and neglected to check if my wifi adapter (14e4:4365) would work. I've tried a few solutions to make it work, but I can't seem to make it happen. I don't have access to internet on the computer-I'm at a hotel on a business trip-but I can transfer files from a laptop with internet to the one with the issue.

```
Result running lspci -nn | grep 0280: 
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

Comment: RTL8111/8168B is your wired ethernet adapter, not wireless. Please edit your question to add the result of this command from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 9):

With a temporary wired ethernet connection, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Detach the ethernet. After a reboot, your wireless should be working.

Comment: Or use USB tethering.

Comment: I was getting unable to locate package bcmwl-kernel-source. I had to do sudo apt update first.