# Can't find wifi on newly installed Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

I just installed ubuntu 14.04, but I found no wifi on it.

```
$ sudo modprobe -r iwlwfi
modprobe: FATAL: module iwlwfi not found
```

with

```
lspci -vq|grep -i wireless
```

I get nothing

while:

```
lspci -vq|grep -i realtek
```

I get

```
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)

lspci -nn |grep -i net
```

I get:

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
```

How to deal with this?

My laptop is a Thinkpad E431

Comment: Please provide some information about your wifi card. What is the output of `lspci -nn | grep -i net`?

Comment: @Andrea Lazzarotto  hi, I've updated info, thanks

Comment: Ok, there seem to be already a solution on this website. Please see this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/334268/ubuntu-13-04-does-not-recognize-wireless-adapter-14e44365

I will mark this as a potential duplicate. If the answer in the other question doesn't help you, we will try to find another solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] works with the Broadcom proprietary driver. Please connect with ethernet and open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

After it finishes, detach the ethernet and your wireless should be working.

Comment: Since you already gave the correct solution in [another question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/334268/ubuntu-13-04-does-not-recognize-wireless-adapter-14e44365) I sent the OP there. But it's good you posted here as well.

Comment: I am going to reward you with a bounty of +50 to say "THANKS" for the solution. After a lot of debugging in my new Ubuntu installation, following these steps solved the problem to me... two times on different moments of the year! : )