# I booted ubuntu 16- It cannot find wifi and doesn't recognize ethernet cable when plugged in

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, internet, ethernet

I am running a dell inspiron 1501.
When I booted ubuntu in my computer and could not find wifi.
So i found this thread:
[can't find wifi on newly installed ubuntu 14](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518504/cant-find-wifi-on-newly-installed-ubuntu-14)
Which I believe will solve my answer(the answer on the forum was to update driver using ethernet cable).
However when I plug in the ethernet cable, its not getting any internet connection. I have tried 2 cables each in different ports on the router and still doesn't work. 1 computer is getting internet from the ethernet connection from the router indicating the router does work. How do I get ethernet connection working! By the way i recommend reading the forum for more information on my problem.
Please Reply ASAP!

```
linux@LinuxComp:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -e 0200 -e 0280 -A2 
05:00.0  Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:0007]
 Kernel driver in use: wl
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX [14e4:170c] (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Dell BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX [1028:01f5]
 Kernel modules: b44
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: Also post: `lspci -nnk | grep -e 0200 -e 0280 -A2`

Comment: linux@LinuxComp:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

Comment: linux@LinuxComp:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -e 0200 -e 0280 -A2
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:0007]
 Kernel driver in use: wl
--
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX [14e4:170c] (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Dell BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX [1028:01f5]
 Kernel modules: b44

Comment: I've got the same device - I haven't tried ethernet but on Lubuntu 14.04 an extra thing I had to do to get the wireless working was disable wireless hotkeys in BIOS - if that doesn't work, enable the hotkey again, boot and press Fn+F2, then disable the hotkey again. (if you have rfkill installed, you can see if wifi is hard blocked with `rfkill list all` and then get the hotkey right before disabling) (I also got the wireless working in Arch with the same procedure plus some extra fiddling) The driver you need for the BCM4311 is b43, as @chili555 will tell you :)

Answer (score 1):

You installed a wrong wireless driver that does not support your wireless adapter and blocked your Ethernet card.

You can fix it this way. Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and reboot. Your Ethernet card will start working.

After that connect to the internet by wire and install the correct wireless firmware by

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```